# Why does not Vector Iterators Incompatible show up in the simplified example?

Tags: for-loop, visual-c++, iterator

I have this simplified example. Everything works fine:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       

typedef std::pair<int, int> pos;

int main() {
    std::vector<pos>::iterator it;
    std::vector<pos> s;
    s.push_back({10, 20});
    s.push_back({11, 30});

    std::vector<pos> target = {{10, 20}, {11, 30},{141, 340}, {151, 340}};

    for (pos i: s) {
        it = std::find(target.begin(), target.end(), i);
    }

    if (it != target.end())
        std::cout << "Element found in myvector: " << it->first << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Element not found in myvector\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, I have a small project, where there is a similar part to the previous code:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> pos;
std::vector<pos> monsters;

    bool Game::isMonsterOnPathToTreasure() {
        avoidMonsterPath = false;
        std::vector<pos> monsterPath;
        getShortestPath(treasurePos, monsterPath);
    
        std::vector<pos>::iterator it;
    
        for (pos monster: monsters) {
            it = std::find(monsterPath.begin(), monsterPath.end(), monster);
        }
    
        if (it != monsters.end()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Unfortunately, in the letter case I got `vector iterators incompatible` error with Visual C++ compiler. My question is, why?

Comment: You didn't show what `monsters` is, but it's probably not a `std::vector<pos>`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry! It is std::vector<pos>.

Comment: You are comparing an iterator to `monsterPath` with an iterator to `monsters`. This is not a legal comparison. You probably meant `it != monsterPath.end()`.